# Approximate Nth root of a given number in C

Tags: c

I was trying to write a program that asks the user for a real number and integer. With the given input the program should calculate the answer. I wanted to do this without math.h 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm is the algorithm I have been following I am certain my loop with int iterate is where I am going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int n, nval;
double A, oldVal, delta;
double newVal;
int i;
int iterate =1;
double root;

int main() {

while ((nval != 2 || A < 0) || n < 2){
printf("Enter real number and integer (A n):");
nval=scanf("%lf %d", &A, &n);
if (nval!=2)
    printf("Error Improperly Formatted Input\n");
else if (A<=0)
    printf("Error: Value of A must be positive\n ");
else if (n<2)
    printf("Error n must be a positive integer >=2\n");

}while ((nval != 2 || A < 0) || n < 2);
if (nval == 2)
        {
            do {
            //THIS has to be error
                newVal=1;
                for (i = 0; i <1/n ; i++) {
                    iterate = iterate * newVal; // these two lines iterate=iterate since oldval = 1
                }

                newVal = (1 / n) * ((n - 1) * oldVal + (A / iterate));
                delta = oldVal - newVal;
                if (delta < 0)
                    delta = delta * (-1);
                root = delta;
            } while (delta > 0.000001);
            printf("Given A = %lf and n = %d, root = %lf\n", A, n, root);
        }
}
```

Comment: Protip: use gdb and breakpoints.

Comment: Please format this and you want to put it on code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "... where I am going wrong."  What was your input, outputs and expected output?

Comment: `1 / n` --> `1.0 / n`

Comment: Say I input 125 and 3, my expected root should be 5 when I run the program my root is zero. Im believe the delta may be unnecessary or in the wrong spot. From break points newVal is 0 oldVal is 0 and so is root and delta.

Comment: Remove 2nd while. `while ((nval != 2 || A < 0) || n < 2);`

Comment: @JamesMoriarty see chux comment (at least 2 occurences). `1 / n` is an integer calculation hence evaluates to `0` unless `n == 1` or `n == -1`. Especially `for (i = 0; i <1/n ; i++)` is suspect as `i` is `int` too.

Comment: `root = delta; } while (delta > 0.000001);`  : `root` can't to be `> 0.000001`

Comment: Since `iterate` is 1  and `newVal` is 1.0 it does not matter how many times your `for` loop does `iterate = iterate * newVal;` although it probably never loops at all (see above comments).

Comment: You also have *undefined behaviour* in `while ((nval != 2 || A < 0) || n < 2) {...}` since you are testing three uninitialised variables.

Comment: @WeatherVane They are global variables. So it will be initialized with default values.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY face palm. My other comments are good though.

Answer (score 3):

fix like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    double A, root;
    int n, nval;

    do{
        printf("Enter real number and integer (A n):");
        nval = scanf("%lf %d", &A, &n);
        if (nval!=2){
            printf("Error Improperly Formatted Input\n");
            while(getchar()!='\n');
        } else if (A < 0)
            printf("Error: Value of A must be positive\n ");
        else if (n < 2)
            printf("Error n must be a positive integer >=2\n");
    }while(nval != 2 || A < 0 || n < 2);

    if(A == 0)
        root = 0.;
#if 0
A = x^n
x = n√A

Xk+1 = 1/n * ((n-1)* Xk + A / Xk^(n-1))
#endif
    else {
        double delta, newVal, oldVal = A / n;
        do {
            newVal = oldVal;
            for(int i = 1; i < n -1; ++i)
                newVal *= oldVal;

            newVal = (A / newVal + (n-1)*oldVal) / n;
            delta = oldVal - newVal;
            if(delta < 0)
                delta = -delta;
            root = oldVal = newVal;
        } while (delta > 0.000001);
    }
    printf("Given A = %lf and n = %d, root = %lf\n", A, n, root);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect I just have two questions to you as I am fairly new to c.

Comment: What is #if 0 and #endif doing? and how do you get the root as in x =rootA?

Comment: @JamesMoriarty `#if 0 ～ #endif` are comments.